# OData Exception The limit of '0' for Top query has been exceeded

Tags: c#, odata, ignite, asp.net-web-api-odata

I am using OData Web API for Version 4, when I try to query OData web Api using `$top` parameter, it return me following exception message.

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. The limit of '0' for Top query has been exceeded. The value from the incoming request is '10'

I am using Apache Ignite dotNet LINQ as data source instead of Entity Framework, my OData controller action method is as follows:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Productioncurvepnl> GetProductioncurvepnl()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting query to ignite");
    var q = AIgniteClient.IgniteClient.Instance.ProductionCurvePnLCache.AsCacheQueryable().Select(c => c.Value);
    return q;
}
```

Comment: Please also include the full URL you are using in the question.

Comment: http://localhost:9000/odata/Productioncurvepnl?$top=10

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Since `Web API OData V6.0.0` you need to enable query options to have this work.
This can be done globally in the `WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config)`

```cs
config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();
```

or directly on your models, for fine grained configuration:

```cs
[Page(MaxTop = 100)]
public class Products
```

If you're using [Model Bound Fluent APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/modelbound-attribute#model-bound-fluent-apis) and cannot add attributes, you'll need to append the query options. For example `.Page(50, 50)`:

```cs
 builder.EntitySet<AccountRecordDto>("Accounts").EntityType.Expand(1, 
 "Transactions").Count().Page(50, 50);
```

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/modelbound-attribute)

Comment: for `config.Select()` to work add `using System.Web.OData.Extensions;` hope helps someone.

Comment: Annotating the class worked for me, but the way you enabled query options did not. I used config.AddODataQueryFilter(new EnableQueryAttribute
            { AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All });

Comment: (N.B. I am using HttpSelfHostConfiguration which is probably why)

Answer (score 5):

Adding below in Startup.cs works for me

```
config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the returned error message the problem most likely is that the `MaxTop` is not defined. You can do that using the `EnableQueryAttribute` on your method like so (*change the value as you see fit*), I used a value of 100.

```
[EnableQuery(MaxTop = 100)]
public IQueryable<Productioncurvepnl> GetProductioncurvepnl()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting query to ignite");
    var q = AIgniteClient.IgniteClient.Instance.ProductionCurvePnLCache.AsCacheQueryable().Select(c => c.Value);
    return q;
}
```

See [EnableQueryAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.enablequeryattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For me [EnableQuery (Max Top = 100)] not working, but [Queryable] working fine. [EnableQuery (Max Top = 100)] should work but don't know why it's not working. Someone knows then please let me know. But for now I am using [Queryable].

Comment: Queryable is deprecated, I have posted an answer with two approaches. Either configuring it globally, or per model

Comment: Neither of the two methods work if you've applied restrictions to the EntityType, for example: 
`builder.EntitySet<AccountRecordDto>("Accounts").EntityType.Expand(1, "Transactions").Count();` 
In this case, I needed to add .Page(50,50) to the EntityType.

Comment: @ogrim neither work for me with asp core which there is no `WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by set setting 'SetMaxTop' property in my .Net 6 Odata Middleware :

```
builder
   .Services
   .AddControllers(mvcoptions => mvcoptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
   .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().Count().OrderBy().Expand().SetMaxTop(1000));
```